# sorting 2 different columns in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort 2 different columns in the same CSV file one column needs to be from highest to lowest and the other one needs to be the opposite lowest to highest.

```
import pandas as pd  


bus1_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus1Data.csv",header=None)


bus1_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)


bus2_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus2Data.csv",header=None)

bus2_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)

def sort_columns_independently(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col]=df[col].sort_values(ascending=False).values
    return df


sorted_bus1_data = sort_columns_independently(bus1_data.copy())
sorted_bus2_data = sort_columns_independently(bus2_data.copy())
```

This code is for sorting every column from high to low which is what I need for the 2nd column but I also need from low to high for the 4th column.
[image]

Comment: plz provide [mre] in text

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['price of bids', 'price of offers'], ascending = [False, True])
```

Comment: when I try this it only sorts for price of bids and not the other variable.

Comment: Pls explain better what you are trying to do